# Camunda/ Activiti Listener on tasks complete

Tags: workflow, activiti, camunda

I need to execute some code when any task is completed.
I found how to add listener on a specific task completion, but not on any task
Any Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the community extension [camunda-bpm-reactor](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-reactor). 
It allows registering Listeners to any event without manually adding them to every bpmn activity.

```
@CamundaSelector(type = "userTask", event = TaskListener.EVENTNAME_CREATE)
public class TaskCreateListener implements TaskListener {

  public TaskCreateListener(EventBus eventBus) {
    eventBus.register(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Activiti you can use the Event listener for this, details here: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#eventDispatcher

Using this approach, you can capture a number of different event types including task completion.

For older Activiti and all Camunda implementations, I would use a parse handler to add the listener on the close event for all tasks. Parse handlers are idea for this sort of thing.

PARSE HANDLERS ARE DESCRIBED HERE: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_hooking_into_process_parsing